# How do I get Multiple CSV files (csv file names will be column names) from a folder to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, finance

I think the title is enough for what is my problem here. I have 100 tickers in a folder. I got all csv files to one list. but I wanna see the tickers name which these are csv file names.
[image]

what should I do for getting all tickers like that. I'm doing it manually but I need a simple way to do that.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

#BİST100-2010.01.01-2020.07.01/ is my folder.
log_total = []
for file in os.listdir('BİST100-2010.01.01-2020.07.01/'):
    log_total.append(pd.read_csv('BİST100-2010.01.01-2020.07.01/'+file+''))
```

by the way after I do that I got this.

[image]

Comment: pd.DataFrame(log_total) ? if it doesnt work create an empty dataframe and concatenate. If it doesn't work maybe try to build the csv directly on multiple ticker...

Answer (score 1):

How do you get to the second picture from that code? I wil give you rough set of steps to follow along with the main function names. you can search through the pandas documentation for more details.

1. initialise some empty lists:  `ticker_names=[]` `dataframes=[]`
2. Loop over the files and read them using `df = pd.read_csv(file_name)`
3. Take just the `Close` column of each single ticker's dataframe: `df = df["Close"]`
4. Keep track of the tickers' names in a list: `ticker_names.append(ticker)`
5. Bring them all together into one dataframe: `final_df = pd.concat(dataframes, left_index=True, right_index=True)`. We uses the indices because you have date-time index values, and we want to keep them all.
6. Then give each column the correct name: `final_df.columns = ticker_names`

You can play around with each of these steps, and I would suggest looking at the [`**pd.merge**`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) documentation.